# jquery slide div from off screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have the fromleft to fly/slide in from off the screen to the middle of the div after the dropdown animation is complete and the fromright to fly/slide in from the right to the middle of the div after the from left is in place

I have been tinkering with it for days but have not had any luck.

Thanks for any help,
Matt

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Banner Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hidden').slideDown(200);
 });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.hidden{
    width:950px;
    height:120px;
    display:none;
    margin:0px auto;
    background-color: #333;
}
#fromright {
    padding-left:140px
}
#fromleft {
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<br />
<br />
<div class="hidden">
<div class="fromleft">Fly in from left</div>
<div class="fromright">Fly in from right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for jQuery's `animate`, run as a callback from the `slideDown`. I've done a quick example here, but it obviously needs a lot of tweaking to be what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/avQFW/

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will point me in the right direction